# how to create an autograder for my java code (test cases provided)?

Tags: java, testing

I am enrolling the data structures course on coursera. It is a specialization, but I only take the data structures independently.
However, I can only submit the programming assignment if I upgrade to the entire specialization...

Within the directory of the assignment, there is also a subdirectory containing a bunch of test cases (eg. `test01` <---- the test file input, and `test01.a` <---- the expected result).
I wonder how can I to test my source code using those test cases, like the online autograder? (write a bash shell script, use JUnit, etc.)

Thanks!

Comment: Please show what these files look like, but in general, yes, use Junit. And if available, use it via Maven/Gradle

Comment: The assignment is asking us to write a function that will point out errors in the usage of different types of brackets.
In ```test01```, it contains only ```()```, and the ```test01.a``` contains ```success```, which is the output of my function should be.
In ```test02```, it has ```{}{}]```, then the content in ```test02.a``` is ```5```, where there is an unpair bracket at position 5.

Comment: Those don't look like Java code, so I don't understand the question of "test my source code". Do you have Java code to read those files and verify the answer? Can you add it to the question? I'm not sure how Coursera wants you to submit the results (if any) for grading, but a site like HackerRank would give you input and results in the online portal.